# Boy scout needing help on Javascript coding

Tags: javascript

I'm a 14 year old boy scout trying to do my programming merit badge, and I'm stuck on this requirement where we have to calculate wind chills? I don't even understand the context of what I'm doing. This is the question Assignment of what to do, "Add another text input – ask for the wind speed, for example.  5. Add some conditional statements that evaluate the wind chill factor.  6. Add some text to display the wind chill result." This is the code, "

```
// JavaScript Document
// Note: lines that start with two backslashes are comments - not code!
var bePrepared = function () {
    // = = = = = = = declare all the variables = = = = = = = =
    var tempF, tempC, myActionText, newText;
    // get the temp (F) from the HTML page
    tempF = document.getElementById('MyInputTemp').value;
    // = = = = = = = convert the temp to Celsius (with only one decimal place)
    tempC = (5 / 9 * (tempF - 32)).toFixed(1);
    // = = = = = = = evaluate the temp (three categories) = = = = = = =
    if (tempF < 60) {
         myActionText = " Take long-johns!";
    }
    if ((tempF >= 60) && (tempC < 75)) {
         myActionText = " Have Fun!";
    }
    if (tempF >= 75) {
         myActionText = " Take Sunscreen!";
    }
    // = = = = = = = build a complete sentence = = = = = = =
    newText = "If the temperature is " + tempF + " &deg;F (" + tempC + " &deg;C): " + myActionText;
    // push the sentence back to the HTML page (using the ID of the markup element: 'myAnswer')
    document.getElementById('myAnswer').innerHTML = newText;
 };
```

and this is some html document that opens up to a browser window, "

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example Javascript Program for Boy Scout Merit Badge</title>
  <script src='JS-Example.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Javascript Programming Example</h1>
  <h2>Enter Temperature (&deg;F):
     <input type="text" id="MyInputTemp"/>
     <input type="button" value="Go!" onclick="bePrepared();"/>
  </h2>
  <h3 id="myAnswer"></h3>
  </body>
  </html>"
```

Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated, because i've spent 2 hours, made no progress, and have exhausted any other place I can to get an answer. I know that the code is laid out terribly, but I dont even know how to do that.

Comment: This is a link to the website with the prompt and code written out properly.                    http://boyslife.org/about-scouts/merit-badge-resources/programming/41261/javascript/

Comment: Hi! I would love to help you out, but your question is unfortunately totally unreadable. You need to format your code so that it can be read.

Comment: "add a text input" = add another `input` tag to your HTML. "conditional statements" = if-else. Is that context helpful? In order to get a good answer on SO, you need to have a more specific question. Edit your question to provide more information about what you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of what you've tried? @LeeonBacchus

Comment: I did exactly what Josiah Keller said, copying the bulk of the code and changing variables to get wind chill, and the website just stopped putting out any responses

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Google Chrome

Comment: I actually just fixed it by debugging the program. Thanks a bunch for your help though. It really means a lot to me that you gave up so much of your time to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a full answer atm, but what the prompt basically wants you to do is add a second text box like the one for temperature that allow a person to input wind chill.

```
<input type="text" id="MyInputWindChill" />
```

Something like that ^ in your HTML document.

Then, in the javascript file, it wants you to reference and store the wind chill value using something like the following:

```
var windChill;
windChill = document.getElementById("MyInputWindChill").value;
```

Then, using the temperature and the wind chill values, it wants you to output an appropriate response by using `if` statements. You can see the basic way to do so in the code already given to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back to me. I tried doing something like this, but when i add in the code, the website i am editing doesn't put out any responses.

Comment: To begin with, did it work originally without changing anything? @LeeonBacchus

Comment: I just emailed my counselor a bit, and he said that we didn't have to do that assignment exactly, so i put in some "if" commands with prompt commands after, and now I have a different issue